# How add capability on iOS certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

when I add capability **"Associated Domains"** on xcode, get out this error

*provisioning profile doesn't include associated domains entitlement*

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had run into the same problem. I solved it by enabling `Associate domains` under `capabilities` section

Try following things :

1. Turn on/off `Associated Domains` in Xcode `capabilities` section.
2. Create provisioning profile again
3. Go to `developer.apple.com` and check capabilities under your app id.

**Xcode:**

[image]

**developer site**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should manually update *Provisioning Profile* via enabling ***Associated Domains*** in **Identifiers** section in *[Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/)* if *Automatic Manage Signing* is not enabled.

[image]